# Taking Photos in landscape having issues in my iOS application

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiimagepickercontroller, ios-camera

I take photos using UIImagePickerController, source type is UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera.
After i captured, the image editing is changing depending upon the orientation. Herewith i attached my snapshot.

Image 1 : i took this image in portrait mode.

[image]

Image 2 : i took this image in landscape mode. here, the top portion is in black color.

[image]

My code is :

```
UIImagePickerController *pickerCamera = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
pickerCamera.delegate = self;
pickerCamera.allowsEditing = YES;
pickerCamera.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
[self presentViewController:pickerCamera animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

I want to rotate the image to portrait. Please help me to solve this issue.